# Azure Blob Storage: Is there a timestamp for blob file?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I need to find out the most recently added blob files to the blob storage. Is there a timestamp associated with each blob file? If not, what's the best way (for easy retrieval) to add it?

Comment: You can look at similar post here for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981788/get-last-blob-in-azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `LastModified` property of the `BlobProperties` class in the `ICloudBlob` object that is returned by the `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` methods of the `CloudBlobContainer`. That will give you the timestamp you are looking for.

Comment: Minor correction to Lukkha's answer: ICloudBlob.Properties.LastModified.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was based on above solution provided by @Lukkha only .
PSB the solution where I used a dictionary with name of blob as key and DateStamp as Value.(K-V pair)

```
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account, account_key=key, endpoint_suffix=domain)
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name=container)

available_json_dict = {} 
for blob in generator:
    blobName = blob.name.split('/')[-1]+'.json'
    available_json_dict[blobName] = last_modified 
    last_modified = blob.properties.last_modified.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    print(blobName,'--->',last_modified)
```